# Фон у body в DLE

Tags: jquery, dle

Как в `DLE` сделать у каждой `fullstory` свой фон `body` в админке?
Нашел такой вариант кода, но он не работает

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").css({"background-image": "url('[xfvalue_background]')"});
});
```

в `body` попадает вот это

```
<body style="background: url("[xfvalue_background]" );">
```

а не как ожидалось, путь к картинке.

Answer (score 0):

Все проблема решена может кому будет полезно, вот код:в fullstory.tpl

```
`<img id="bg-target" src="[xfvalue_image_url_bgbody]" alt="" 
 style="display:none;">`
```

и файле скрипт  пишем код:

```
`$(document).ready(function(){
   bgTarget = $("#bg-target").attr("src");
    if (bgTarget !== "") {
    $("body").css({"background": "url("+bgTarget+") no-repeat fixed"});
}
});`
```

В админке создаем доп.поле с изображением и называем его как вам удобно, у меня оно называется(bgbody).